# How to add two numbers without concatenating them as strings?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

The `parseInt(sum3) + parseInt(sum5)` is not adding the two variables. It just concatenates them. How can I add the two?

I know I can just manually create another variable and put the output of sum3 there and put the output of sum5 in another variable and add them like that but I idk I think that's cheating. So **how can I add the sum3 and sum5?**

```
// sum of 3
let max3 = parseInt(1000);
let sum3 = 0;

for ( let three=3; three<=max3; three++ ){
    sum3+=three
}


// sum of 5
let max5 = parseInt(1000);
let sum5 = 0

for (let five=5; five<=max5; five++){
  sum5+=five
}


// sum of 3 and 5

document.write("Sum of 3 = " + sum3 + "<br/>"
   + "Sum of 5 = " + sum5 + "<br/>" + 
    "Sum of 3 and 5 = " + parseInt(sum3) + parseInt(sum5));
```

Comment: No need for the `parseInt()` and just adding extra parentheses will fix it: `"Sum of 3 and 5 = " + (sum3 + sum5)`

Comment: Here's a version without document.write and duplicate code: https://jsfiddle.net/vjto3ygu/

Answer (score 1):

It's just because you're using `+` in the context of string concatenation.

Should be:

```
document.write("Sum of 3 = " + sum3 + "<br/>"
   + "Sum of 5 = " + sum5 + "<br/>" + 
    "Sum of 3 and 5 = " + (sum3 + sum5));
```

Or you really should use:

```
document.write(`Sum of 3 = ${sum3} <br/>
        Sum of 5 = ${sum5} <br/>
        Sum of 3 and 5 = ${sum3 + sum5}`);
```

Comment: Now just get rid of the `parseInt()` and you're good.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen True

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap `parseInt(sum3) + parseInt(sum5)` in a () bracket and it should do the job.

```js
// sum of 3
let max3 = parseInt(1000);
let sum3 = 0;

for (let three = 3; three <= max3; three++) {
  sum3 += three
}


// sum of 5
let max5 = parseInt(1000);
let sum5 = 0

for (let five = 5; five <= max5; five++) {
  sum5 += five
}


// sum of 3 and 5

document.write("Sum of 3 = " + sum3 + "<br/>" +
  "Sum of 5 = " + sum5 + "<br/>" +
  "Sum of 3 and 5 = " + (parseInt(sum3) + parseInt(sum5)));
```

Answer (score -1):

You concatenate both string values with the use of '+'.

Don't combine this with string so '+' will still work as expected.

```js
// sum of 3
let max3 = 1000;
let sum3 = 0;

for (let three=3; three<=max3; three++){
    sum3+=three
}


// sum of 5
let max5 = 1000;
let sum5 = 0

for (let five=5; five<=max5; five++){
  sum5+=five
}


// sum of 3 and 5
let totalSum = sum3 + sum5

document.write("Sum of 3 = " + sum3 + "<br/>"
   + "Sum of 5 = " + sum5 + "<br/>" + 
    "Sum of 3 and 5 = " + totalSum);
```

Comment: The question is easy, this is the JS tag, and it's 2022. It's a duplicate. You're supposed to search for the dupe before posting an answer.

Comment: OP explicitly mentions in the question that they know that they can store the sum in another variable and work around the problem like that.